# Msbuild conditional constructs with appveyor

Tags: msbuild, appveyor

I am trying to build my application in multiple configurations Debug/Release with AppVeyor. The project builds successfully if there aren't any conditional constructs in my proj files. Whereas if I have a conditional construct the build fails. If I run the build locally using `msbuild project.csproj` it works fine. I am not sure is there are any configurations that needs to be in place or I am doing something wrong. Below are the code snippets.
For brevity just including the bits necessary

**Appveyor.yml**

```
configuration: 
 - Release
 - Debug

build:
  parallel: true
  project: project.proj
  verbosity: minimal
```

**project.proj**

```
<Target Name="NameTest1">       
        <MSBuild Projects="Project1.csproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);" ContinueOnError="false"/>
        <MSBuild Projects="Project2.csproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);" ContinueOnError="false"/>
        <MSBuild Projects="Project3.csproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);" ContinueOnError="false" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'"/>  -->AppVeyor build Fails Here 
</Target>
```

**Another proj file being used by Project.proj**

```
<Choose>
        <when Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
            <ItemGroup>
                <BinFiles Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.exe"/>
                <BinFiles Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll"/>
                <BinFiles Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll.config"/>
                <BinFiles Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.exe.config"/>
            </ItemGroup>
        </when>
    </Choose>
```

Appveyor fails at both Condition as well as Choose/When constructs. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Is it Windows or Linux/macOS build?

Comment: @FeodorFitsner its a windows build

Comment: Would you be able to do a simple repro in a public repository?